# Windows 8 RT app control Tapped event firing multiple times

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a basic **Image** control that I added in XAML to a control I am making.  Then in my **OnApplyTemplate** method in the control I am making I add a *Tapped* event handler to the image.

```
(GetTemplateChild("PART_quarter") as Image).Tapped += tcNoteSelector_Tapped;
```

In the tapped event handler I have the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sender: {0}", (sender as Image).Name);
e.Handled = true;
```

My problem is that this is firing three times.  I have multiple images using the same handler and they all have the same problem.  I tried commenting out all but one of the event handler wire up lines but that didn't make a difference.  Is this supposed to happen or did I do something wrong?  If this is supposed to happen how am I supposed to determine a single logical tap from the multiple times the event is firing?

Comment: Just for giggles, do you happen to have 3 instances of the control on the page?

Comment: I have 3 image controls, all named separately, let me try and see if commenting one makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnApplyTemplate` can be called multiple times so it could be attaching your `Tap` event handler multiple times. A bit hacky, but removing then adding the event handler should work in most cases to ensure the event handler is attached only once.

```
Image img = GetTemplateChild("PART_quarter") as Image;
if(img != null)
{
   img.Tapped -= tcNoteSelector_Tapped;
   img.Tapped += tcNoteSelector_Tapped;
}
```

Comment: That's what it is.  I added a debug line in the *OnApplyTemplate* method and it printed the same number of times as my event handler debug statement.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the cause of the issue but I can't actually work around it.  I tried using this method but it didn't work.  I even tried using some locking and such to make sure it wasn't threads running at the same time.  Thoughts?

Comment: @BlargleMonster - Is it still not working? If not, here's a similar approach with properties. Might be work trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971683/when-do-i-unsubscribe-from-events-inside-custom-control

Comment: It's the strangest thing, I added multiple debugging lines and the locking I added to the question above and it still writes to the output multiple times.  Yet when I raise another event from the event handler I registered that event only seems to happen once.  So I'm not sure if I'm crazy or it's some sort of half-bug.  It seems I'm able to get it to function by using your suggestion though so that's good enough for me.

Comment: The `OnApplyTemplate` event is still being called multiple times which is why your debug output is writing multiple times. The difference with the event handler is that you're removing it then reattaching so it ends up with one event handler attached when `OnApplyTemplate` is called for the final time. However that piece of detaching/attaching code is still being called the same number of times as your debug code which is why, without the detaching, your original `Tap` event got called multiple times.